# Uninstall a latex version if two are installed

Tags: package-management, version, latex, uninstall

I have two version of latex installed, see here:

```
josef@josef-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~$ whereis latex
latex: /usr/bin/latex /home/josef/bin/latex /usr/share/man/man1/latex.1.gz
```

I want to uninstall the one at /home/josef. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al /home/josef/bin/latex`?

Comment: @GAD3R `josef@josef-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~$ ls -al /home/josef/bin/latex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 josef josef 22 Apr 25 14:16 /home/josef/bin/latex -> /usr/bin/miktex-pdftex`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @GAD3R, I just had to uninstall miktex and remove the symlink, now it's gone :)

Answer (score 1):

As GAD3R suggested, I could see that the version of latex comes from a miktex installation:

```
josef@josef-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-3:~$ ls -al /home/josef/bin/latex 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 josef josef 22 Apr 25 14:16 /home/josef/bin/latex -> /usr/bin/miktex-pdftex
```

Then I just had to uninstall miktex (I did via Synaptic) and remove the symlink with `rm -i /home/josef/bin/latex`.